# Erro ao implementar IA simples em C#

Tags: c#, inteligência-artificial, nuget

Gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar, se existe algum exemplo simples ou nuget para IA, que seja exclusivamente em C# para reconhecimento de objetos e leitura OCR, usando um modelo pré treinado (Onnx por exemplo).
Eu gostaria de usar um stream de vídeo por isso não pode ser Azure ou Google (pagos), mas se tiver um exemplo gratuito com imagem estática já ajuda.

Tentei esse Yolo https://github.com/AlturosDestinations/Alturos.Yolo mas não está funcionando

```
using (var yoloWrapper = new YoloWrapper("yolo9000.cfg", "yolo9000.weights", "9k.names"))
{
 var items = yoloWrapper.Detect(@"webcapture.jpg");
}
```

aparece o erro

```
System.DllNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80131524
  Message=Não é possível carregar a DLL 'x64\yolo_cpp_dll_cpu.dll': Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
  Source=Alturos.Yolo
```

Comment: a mensagem do erro parece bem clara... você não tem todas as referências necessárias adicionadas ao projeto... agora a sua pergunta não tem nada a ver com o código apresentado. Para captura e processamento de vídeo, você pode olhar as bibliotecas do OpenCV

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. A referência aparece tanto no visual studio quanto na pasta sem erros ou alertas, vi que outras pessoas tiveram esse problema, por isso estava procurando algo similar em C#, tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Você verificou se essa biblioteca é compatível com a versão do .net que está utilizando?

Comment: voce verificou se a biblioteca esta na local correto, na pasta `x64` ? `x64\yolo_cpp_dll_cpu.dll` ?